# Como sumar el resultado de un for y mostrarlo con un cin. C++

Tags: c++, imprimir

**1. Quiero un programa que imprima numeros primos del 1 al 100 de forma descendente y luego al final sumar todo, es decir sumar 25 números que debería de ser.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
bool esPrimo(int numero);
 
int main()
{
    for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
        if (esPrimo(i))
      cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
 
bool esPrimo(int numero)
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
        if (numero % i == 0)
            k++;
    return k == 2;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cual es la pregunta? Has expuesto lo que quieres pero no qué es lo que no sabes hacer. Aunque pueda parecer obvio qué es lo que quieres, es importante que lo pongas de forma explícita porque ayuda a focalizar las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

El detalle que me percaté es que la validación que está dentro de tu ciclo `for` está bien, pero no estás imprimiendo nada cuando ésta condición se cumpla:

```
for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
    if (esPrimo(i)) // si es primo, no imprime nada.
  cout << endl;
return 0;
```

Ahora para la suma de los primos, definamos una variable llamada `suma`
inicializada en `0` dentro del `int main()`:

```
int main()
{
    int suma = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Y dentro del `for`, nuevamente hacemos la validación de que si es primo se irá sumando dichos números, así sucesivamente en cada ciclo que se repita. Luego mostramos en consola el resultado final de `suma`, cuando el ciclo ya haya terminado y ya haya sumado todos los primos (almacenado en `suma`):

```
for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--){
    if (esPrimo(i))
        cout << i << " ";
    if (esPrimo(i))
        suma += i;
}   
cout << endl;
cout << "la suma de los primos es: " << suma << endl;
```

Tu código final sería así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool esPrimo(int numero);

int main()
{
    int suma = 0;
    
    for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i--){
        if (esPrimo(i))
            cout << i << " ";
        if (esPrimo(i))
            suma += i;
    }   
    cout << endl;
    cout << "La suma de los primos es: " << suma << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

bool esPrimo(int numero)
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numero; i++)
        if (numero % i == 0)
            k++;
    return k == 2;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 97 89 83 79 73 71 67 61 59 53 47 43 41 37 31 29 23 19 17 13 11 7 5 3 2
// la suma de los primos es: 1060
```